# Allow multiple purchases of same in app purchase

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

Right now i'm allowing multiple in app purchases. 3 month subscription, etc. But i cannot get a renewable purchase because apple wont allow it. So currently when a user goes to buy another 3 month subscription it gives the message that they've already purchases this item and wont allow them to purchase it again. I figure this has something to do with the product id? Is there a way to allow this not to happen and purchase the same product with the same product id multiple times? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can they buy it again once the 3 months has expired ?

Comment: nope it says you've already purchased this item

Comment: What "type" of in-app did you used? (Consumable, Non-Consumable, Auto-Renewable Subscriptions, Free Subscription, Non-Renewing Subscription)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your product is not a non consumable product it is *Non-Renewing Subscriptions* instead. For further detail check [check this link](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4009) and go to *Types of In-App Purchases* this section.

Comment: so non renewing subscriptions cannot be purchased again?

Comment: *on-renewing subscriptions*
Ex: **One-month subscriptions,
Location service subscriptions**
Description: You can purchase these items again after the subscription period ends.